# Why my android app name is displaying this.. androidx.multidex.....? Please see the image

Tags: android-studio, displayname-attribute

After I install my apk ,  my app name is displaying as below. Is there any thing I'm missing on parameter setting..? Does any one has similar issue..?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you set a valid `android:label` for you `<application>` in the `manifest.xml`? [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#label)

Comment: plz share strings.xml

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Adding android:label solved my problem :)

Comment: Adding android:label does not help :(